# Emacs takes a very long time to open a TeX file

Tags: latex, auctex

After a fresh install of Emacs (GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (i686-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-18)
and AUCTeX (last version from ELPA) on Windows Vista, when I open a TeX file, Emacs takes an extremely long time to load the file (>2minutes).
In the minibuffer I see a message telling `Applying style hooks...`; the delay starts exactly when I see this message.
After this delay, when I open the message buffer I see something like this:

```
Applying style hooks...
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/geometry.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/amssymb.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/amsmath.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/amstext.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/amsbsy.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/amsopn.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/amsthm.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/pdfsync.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/epigraph.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/multicol.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/makeidx.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/fancyhdr.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/footmisc.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/relsize.elc...done
Loading c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.7/style/bm.elc...done
Applying style hooks... done
```

(Incidentally, the base names of the `*.elc` files are the names the packages I use in my TeX file).

With Emacs 24.5 I didn't have this problem.

Any idea how to solve this issue? How to disable the loading of these style hooks?

If I open an empty TeX file, this delay is significantly reduced.
If I run emacs without my init file, this delay disappears.

**Edit:** Thank you for your comments.
After your suggestions, I bisected my init file and I localized the code responsible for this delay. That was `(setq TeX-parse-self t)`.

Comment: Loading the style hooks is normal. Emacs 24.5 did it too. What version of Windows are you using? Do you have the same problem with other Emacs 25.1 binaries? What is Emacs doing — at least you could open `*Messages*` before opening the TeX file and see whether the delay is before or after loading the style hooks. Do you have any problems with an empty `.tex` file? With a non-TeX file? Can you reproduce the problem if you rename your init file so that Emacs doesn't load it?

Comment: "If I run emacs without my init file, this delay disappears" then nobody will be able to help you unless you post a **minimal** init file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the latest version built for Emacs, a it seems it wasn't compiled with the correct flags originally – https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-11/msg00450.html

Comment: Do you experience these long parsing times for every documents or just for one in particular? In the latter case, can you provide a minimal LaTeX document that causes long parsing? I've never experienced parsing times longer than one second, what you're reporting looks very strange and could be important to be fixed, if you can help us finding the culprit.

Comment: @giordano, I haven't a fresh installed emacs at hand.  But I remember, that after having installed emacs and especially AUCTex on a blank computer, AUCTeX tries to search the TeX-Directories, in order to determine which package is installed and what magical help AUCTeX should provide.  I am running AUCTeX myself always with `(TeX-parse-self t)`.

Comment: @Jan That doesn't happen when you open a file but when you insert usepackage or documentclass commands, in order to complete only with actually available packages and classes. In addition, you can disable this feature, but it isn't controlled by TeX-parse-self variable.