# Pinpointing an I-search Bug

Tags: isearch

I have a very annoying bug in my isearch behaviour; the buffer gets indented (modified) when I enter the first letter during isearch. I've checked all hooks named `isearch.*hook` but I can't find anything that differs from Vanilla Emacs. I think it only happens in `auto-indent-mode`. I need ideas on how to track down such bugs and this one in particular.

Comment: Does it happen when you start emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?

Comment: What @Dan said. If the answer is no, then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. You can use command `comment-region` to comment (or with `C-u` uncomment) a region of text.

Comment: Nope, @Dan, it only happens together with my add-ons.

Comment: Then it's something in your init file, I'm afraid.  Your best bet is to do as @Drew suggests: recursively bisect your init file until you isolate the code that's giving you the problem.

Comment: [how do I troubleshoot emacs](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems) may be helpful