# transient-mark-mode highlighting doesn't work until buffer display is refreshed

Tags: highlighting

I recently upgraded to Emacs 25.1.2, and `transient-mark-mode` no longer works properly - *sometimes*.

The behavior I see is that pressing `C-spc` and moving the cursor to select an area of text doesn't automatically highlight the area. If I move to another window and return, or switch to a different window and come back, I see the selection highlighted.

I also see the section highlighted if the cursor comes across a parenthesis. Since I have show-paren-mode turned on, the parens get highlighted, and the selection also gets highlighted.

It's suddenly working as expected as I type this, but it wasn't working for the past couple of days, in spite of restarts.

How do I debug what might be happening?

Comment: [Basic troubleshooting](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems). If you can reproduce this with `emacs -Q` it's an actual bug that ought to be reported to the Emacs maintainers.

Comment: The problem hasn't recurred yet. But once it does, I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case the issue was caused by using package "expand-region". A workaround for the issue is to add (setq shift-select-mode nil) to Emacs config file. For more details, see https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/issues/229 (and related issues #220, #225).