# Block syntax highlighting breaks in org-mode in this case, how to fix?

Tags: org-mode, themes, syntax-highlighting

I have this in my `init.el` to enable block code syntax highlighting in org-mode:

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

I have also this for `org-babel`:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((emacs-lisp . t)
   (ditaa . t)))
```

when I insert source code <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd> to draw something using [ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) (same problem with `emacs-lisp` code, it seems to be a general SRC code block problem), the syntax highlighting breaks when I write this line:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file "./foo.png" :cmdline -r
```

**No syntax highlighting but code can be evaluated**

[image]

However, when I leave only `#+BEGIN_SRC` sitting alone in the first line I get the highlighting right, but code will not be evaluated in this case when I hit `C-c C-c`. Even one space after `SRC` is enough to break that syntax highlighting. What is going on? Can anyone help me fix it?

**Syntax highlighting is right but code cannot be evaluated**

[image]

**Note**

- GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian)
- GNU Emacs 25.1.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-09-29; nothing changed.
- Org mode version 9.0.4 (release_9.0.4-248-gdef8a8)
- Org mode version 9.0.5 (release_9.0.5-288-g4caad0) problem presists
- theme used is `moe-dark`

**Update**

When I run `emacs --vanilla` from the terminal, the problem disappears. So what is going on? What to do next to find the cause from here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Emacs 25.1.91.1, so upgrading might help if possible

Comment: same problem after upgrading to emacs 25.1.2

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue in org-mode v 9.3.8. I don't have anything similar to your polymode package though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By commenting out this line in my `init.el` problem was removed, the line was related to [polymode](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode) package.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org" . poly-org-mode))
```

That's it. This [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems) was very helpful.