# Disabling automatic line highlighting

Tags: minor-mode

Every time I open a new file in emacs, hl-line-mode is enabled. I have put

```
(global-hl-line-mode -1)
(hl-line-mode -1)
```

in my init.el, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Find out what is turning the mode on. If you don't see the same behavior when starting Emacs without an init file (`emacs -Q`) then recursively bisect your init file to find out where you are turning it on. Look after you turn it off in your init file.

Comment: The commands given above are the last two in my init.el file.

Comment: I have also verified that this file is being used by emacs.

Comment: This is infuriating...I want to love emacs so much, but right now it's really hard.

Comment: Can you turn it of after your emacs is loaded? Aka eval `M-:` `(global-hl-line-mode -1)` and does this turn the hightlight off? I gues some mode has this set as a hook when it is being loaded. So the question is which packages do you have installed, and checking which ones might do it.

Comment: If those are the last two lines in your init, then something earlier in the file is causing the problem. You really do need to follow @Drew s advice to find out what the source is. [more details on troubleshooting](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems)

Comment: Took the easy way out and changed the highlighting color to coincide with my background...lame.

Comment: Incidentally, I am using Prelude emacs https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude#getting-to-know-prelude