# My emacs doesn't contain a function in the online emacs manual

Tags: functions, commands

Command `comment-line` is not recognized by my version of emacs. How can I install this function?

UPDATE: It may be relevant that my system shows at least two emacs, at /usr/local/bin/emacs; and at /usr/bin/emacs24. The second one is what I use; the first one cannot be launched. I have periodically removed and reinstalled emacs for reasons I cannot now recall.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that your version of Emacs does not have command `comment-line`? What does `C-h f comment-line` tell you?

What version of Emacs do you have? `M-x emacs-version`

`comment-line` is defined in library `newcomment.el`, which is available with Emacs 23 and later.

If you try to invoke `comment-line` (e.g. `M-x comment-line`), library `newcomment.el` should be loaded automatically, defining the command completely. But this assumes you have Emacs 23 or later.

Comment: I'm using version 24.5.1. `C-h-f comment-line` does not find it. `M-x comment-line` does not download the file.

Comment: @MathManM How did you install Emacs? The problem you describe here and in your [other question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30768/disabling-automatic-line-highlighting) suggest you're not running a standard version of Emacs.

Comment: @Tyler I don't recall how I installed it. It was a while ago. However, I evidently have multiple builds of emacs. See edit above.

Comment: The function first appeared in `25.0.90`, so bad luck.