# C-x C-f results in the error message: "Wrong type argument: commandp, counsel-find-file"

Tags: key-bindings, debugging, find-file

I opened Emacs, and executed `C-x C-f`. A beep sounded and the following message appeared in the status line:

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, counsel-find-file
```

All I wanted was to open an existing file. What's wrong with my Emacs, and how can I fix it?

---

GNU Emacs 25.1.1
macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

Comment: It sounds like you might be new to Emacs. If so, you might want to get a little more familiar with plain Emacs, before adding 3rd-party packages, changing key bindings, etc. (Please ignore, if I misunderstand.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have bound `C-x C-f` to the command `counsel-find-file`, which is part of the [Counsel Package](https://melpa.org/#/counsel). Apparently, the counsel package is not getting loaded by your config files, so when you try to call it, Emacs doesn't know what you mean.

First, I'd try installing counsel via `package-list-packages`. If that doesn't fix the problem, or if counsel is already installed, something in your config is broken. If that's the case, start here: [How do I troubleshoot Emacs problems?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems)

Comment: I think if counsel was not loaded, the error would be `command-execute: Symbol's function definition is void: counsel-find-file`, no?

Comment: I tried this from emacs -Q, and got the reported error

Comment: Oh, it seems to have changed across Emacs versions. In 24.5 I get `function definition is void`, in 26 I get `Wrong type argument: commandp`.

Comment: Thank you. Installing `counsel` via `package-list-packages` did the trick.