# Since upgrading to emacs 26.1 C-SPC behaviour changed and I have to press it twice to set-mark

Tags: mark, emacs26, transient-mark-mode

Since upgrading to Emacs 26.1 <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> behaviour changed and I have to press it twice (most of the time) to set mark, which disrupts my flow and is hard on my thumb joint (don't ask).

I'd like to understand what is changed and possibly have the old behaviour reinstated. I have `transient-mark-mode` set to `t`.

Comment: Can you reproduce this after starting emacs with `emacs -Q`? This is the first step in troubleshooting most Emacs problems: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: Provide a step-by-step recipe. Each command, by default, deactivates the mark when it is finished. That includes yanking. But deactivating does not remove the mark - it is still set. It's unclear just what your problem is, or what you expect. So far, the question is unclear, and so risks being deleted. Please try to clarify, providing a step-by-step recipe.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic / not about emacs.

Comment: Please don't provide the answer as an edit in the question: put it as an answer.

Comment: @Stefan - I will as soon as I am allowed to answer my own question (which I currently cannot do)

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of embarassing.

At the same time of the emacs upgrade to 26, I also installed an alternate desktop notification engine (dunst, which I need because at work I use i3wm).

On receiveing a notification, dunst pops up a transient window and *the default config binding for dismissing it is:* <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>. I also happen to have a fair number of (nagios, moslty) notifications at any time. So dunst was grabbing the shortcut intended for emacs (apparently, it steals the shortcut regardless of what has focus at the time)

I did not realize this until I noticed that:

- <kbd>C-h-l</kbd> never showed repeat <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> occurences
- Something was flashing on the desktop at the extreme right ov my FOV (that's were notifications pop up) just after I was hitting <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>

Reconfiguring that binding removed my woes.