# How to fix reftex-toc numbering?

Tags: latex, reftex-mode

I have used `reftex-toc` for a while without problem, but a while back it started to show the wrong numbering in the toc-buffer. I don't think I have changed any settings. The latex-output is not affected, so it seems to only be a problem in the parsing of the buffer.

[image: incorrect numbering by reftex-toc]

`tex-clean`, refreshing the buffer or restart of Emacs does not help.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you load Emacs without your init file? ie., `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Tyler No, it doesn't.

Comment: That usually means there's something in your config causing the problem. Some pointers on debugging it are here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: @Tyler I seem to have found the problem. I had lots of section commands commented out in the file, and reftex-toc must have picked these up and parsed them anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had lots of section commands commented out in the file, and `reftex-toc` picked these up and parsed them anyway.

Not sure if this is a bug, but to remove commented section commands solved the problem.