# Why is cursor moving after a save?

Tags: window-splitting, cursor

When working with the same buffer in multiple windows within one frame, it seems like the location of the cursor in, say, window A gets inadvertently set as a marker such that right after the buffer using C-x C-s in window B, the cursor in B jumps to the same cursor location as in A.

Is this normal behavior?  What are the commands or settings controlling this?

Comment: This isn't normal, and I can't reproduce it on my Emacs. Most likely you have something in your config that's causing an unexpected interaction: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: Thanks for verifying it's an issue on my end and providing the link.  i will investigate.

Comment: Could be `(save-place-mode t)`

Comment: Can't find this command in any of my .emacs files, but it does give me an idea to either look for "save" in these files or add '(save-place-mode f)' to my personal.el file.