# How to capture fields from bibtex by using org-ref

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

I want to use emacs org-mode to take notes of my bibliography. I am trying to capture some fields from a bibtex file and insert them into an org file with the `org-ref-open-bibtex-notes`. This is not working for me.

For example, I have a `bibliography.bib`:

```
@comment -*- org-ref-bibliography-notes: "./articles.org" -*-

@article{Mouhot2010,
  author = {Mouhot, C. and Villani, C.},  
  title = {{Landau Damping}},
  journal = {J. Math. Phys.},
  number = {1},
  volume = {51},
  year = {2010},
  doi = {10.1063/1.3285283},
}
```

The first line sets the local variable `org-ref-bibliography-notes` to `"./articles.org"`. If I run `M-x org-ref-open-bibtex-notes`, the file `./articles.org` is populated with:

```
# -*- org-ref-default-bibliography: ("./articles.bib") -*-

** TODO - 
 :PROPERTIES:
  :Custom_ID: 
  :AUTHOR: 
  :JOURNAL: 
  :YEAR: 
  :VOLUME: 
  :PAGES: 
  :DOI: 
  :URL: 
 :END:

cite:
```

**The bibtex fields like `author` or `year` are empty. How can I capture these fields?** Alternatively, I would like to get the following output:

```
# -*- org-ref-default-bibliography: ("./articles.bib") -*-

* Mouhot and Villani (2010): Landau Damping
  :PROPERTIES:
   :Custom_ID: cite:Mouhot2010
  :END:
```

I am using emacs 24.5.1, org 20190812 (orgmode elpa) and org-ref 20190802.1327 (melpa)

Comment: This works as expected for me, **if point (i.e., the cursor) is in the entry when I call the function**. If point is anywhere before the entry then I get an empty note like you see. Can you confirm you still have a problem when you put the cursor inside the entry before you try to open the note?

Comment: @Tyler I have tried putting the cursor on Mouhot2010, before it, after it, inside one of the other entries like author or journal, before and after the last brackets, and selecting (C-space) some regions or selecting the whole entry. I get the same result everytime :(

Comment: in that case I'm not sure what else to suggest. As I said, it works for me, so we'll need more information to figure this out. Maybe something here will help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: @Tyler Commented the line `(setq-default case-fold-search nil)` in my .emacs and it worked. The org-ref command probably uses case-insensitive searches. Thanks for leading me in the right direction. Should I close this?

Comment: That's kind of interesting, maybe a bug in org-ref? @johnkitchin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the statement `(setq-default case-fold-search nil)` conflicts somehow with the `org-ref-open-bibtex-notes`. The [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CaseFoldSearch) mentions that `case-fold-search` set to nil means that searches are case-sensitive, and non-nil means searches are case-insensitive. This variable affects how lots of programs work (as in this case).

---

On the final question, the `:PROPERTIES:` output can be configured, e.g.

```
(setq org-ref-note-title-format
   "* %A%y - %t
 :PROPERTIES:
   :Custom_ID: %k
   :AUTHOR: %4a
   :JOURNAL: %j *%v*, %p (%y)
   :DOI: %D
   :URL: %U 
 :END:

")
```

For help on scape codes like %A or %k, see `M-x describe-function` RET `org-ref-reftex-format-citation`.

After running `M-x org-ref-bibliography-notes` in the `bibliography.bib` buffer, I get

```
# -*- org-ref-default-bibliography: ("./articles.bib") -*-

* Mouhot2010 - Landau Damping
 :PROPERTIES:
   :Custom_ID: Mouhot2010
   :AUTHOR: Mouhot \& Villani
   :JOURNAL: J. Math. Phys. *51*, (2010)
   :DOI: 10.1063/1.3285283
   :URL: 
 :END:

cite:Mouhot2010
```

Since I use `org-ref-open-bibtex-notes` a lot, I have defined the `C-c o` shortcut:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c o")  'org-ref-open-bibtex-notes)
```