# Overwrite global-set-key in major-mode

Tags: key-bindings

In my `.emacs` file I have bound the tab-key to a function called `smart-tab`.

```
(global-set-key [(tab)] 'smart-tab)

(defun smart-tab ()
  "This smart tab is minibuffer compliant: it acts as usual in
   the minibuffer. Else, if mark is active, indents region. Else if
   point is at the end of a symbol, expands it. Else indents the
   current line."
  (interactive)
  (if (minibufferp)
      (minibuffer-complete)
    (if mark-active
        (indent-region (region-beginning)
                       (region-end))
      (if (looking-at "\\_>") ;; \_> end of symbol
          (dabbrev-expand nil)
        (indent-for-tab-command)))))
```

I'm using the module `xah-find`. So I also load it in my `.emacs` file.

```
(require 'xah-find)
```

When I'm now using e.g. the function `xah-find-text` all the results are printed in a temporary buffer `*xah-find output*` which is in the major mode `∑xah-find`.

This major mode binds the tab-key to `xah-find-next-match`. But in my case the tab-key is still bound to my function `smart-tab` instead.

I would like to overwrite the global set tab-key in this major mode, so that in the major mode `∑xah-find` the tab-key is bound to `xah-find-next-match` instead to `smart-tab`.

Comment: That's what is supposed to happen: global-bindings are masked by local bindings. So any bindings provided by your active major mode (xah-find) should mask your global bindings. When you're in the buffer `*xah find output*`, what does `C-h k <TAB>` report? Also, what does `C-h v major-mode` report?

Comment: What @Tyler said. I inspected the [source code](https://github.com/xahlee/xah-find/blob/master/xah-find.el). There is no obvious reason there why the normal behavior wouldn't work. But, I know that ergoemacs does some creasy things with keymaps. Do you have ergoemacs activated?

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-04-13. I don't know ergoemacs, so I assume it is not activated.

Comment: @Tyler : `C-h k <TAB>` reports that it is bound to `smart-tab`. `C-h v major-mode` reports `xah-find-output-mode`.

Comment: `C-h k <TAB>` should also tell us which map `smart-tab` was found in, ie. `(found in global-map)` or `(found in xah-find-file-map)`?

Comment: It is found in the global map. Here the begin of the output of `C-h k <TAB>` : `<tab> runs the command smart-tab (found in global-map), which is an
interactive Lisp function in ‘~/.emacs’.`

Comment: That's very strange. TAB key is not getting set properly in the `xah-find-file-map`, or possibly there is some code in your init file that is unsetting it. Maybe something here will help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
(global-set-key [(tab)] 'smart-tab)
```

to this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'smart-tab)
```

and unless restarting Emacs, also evaluate this once:

```
(global-unset-key [(tab)])
```

---

What you weren't noticing (n.b. posting the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> output from Emacs in the different situations would have helped others to see what was happening sooner) was that Emacs was showing you two *different* key representations:

- `TAB`
- `<tab>`

You may also have seen the phrase `"TAB (translated from <tab>)"` in some situations.

These are two separate events, and which of them is sent to Emacs when you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> on your keyboard is contextual.  Terminals send `TAB` (aka ASCII control character 9, or `^I` or `C-i`), so if you are running Emacs in a terminal it will receive a `TAB`.  GUIs on the other hand will differentiate the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key from <kbd>C-i</kbd>, and send a `<tab>` event.

By default Emacs wants to do the same thing regardless, so that it has the same behaviour in both terminal and GUI environments; and so in the absence of any specific binding for `<tab>` Emacs will translate the event to `TAB` and use the binding for that.

So you ought to use `TAB` (like `xah-find.el` does) because that representation works in both terminals and GUI frames, and will mesh better with other Emacs functionality.

As you were binding `<tab>` and your GUI was *sending* a `<tab>` event, that binding took precedence over the major mode binding for `TAB` -- because the *translation* to `TAB` happens only in the absence of an explicit binding for `<tab>`.

(And in a terminal your `<tab>` binding wouldn't have had any effect at all.)

Comment: Excellent answer!!! Solved my problem. Are there more keys than tab which are different for GUI and terminal? Where can I find a list?

Comment: `C-h i g (elisp)Function Keys` is probably the thing to read first.  You can delve into the `local-function-key-map` and other Translation Keymaps details from there, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I did now the following to reproduce the problem on the following emacs:

"GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.7)
 of 2019-04-11, modified by Debian"

Running emacs from shell with `emacs -Q` Then putting the following code into the scratch buffer:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp")

(require 'package)
(setq package-load-list
      '((xah-find t)))
(package-initialize)

(require 'xah-find)

(global-set-key [(tab)] 'smart-tab)

(defun smart-tab ()
  "This smart tab is minibuffer compliant: it acts as usual in
   the minibuffer. Else, if mark is active, indents region. Else if
   point is at the end of a symbol, expands it. Else indents the
   current line."
  (interactive)
  (if (minibufferp)
      (minibuffer-complete)
    (if mark-active
        (indent-region (region-beginning)
                       (region-end))
      (if (looking-at "\\_>") ;; \_> end of symbol
          (dabbrev-expand nil)
        (indent-for-tab-command)))))
```

I executed `M-x eval-buffer`. Then I tried the same things as in my previous post. And in the *xah-find output* buffer the tab key is still bound to `smart-tab`.

Note:
The xah-find.el file is in this location on my computer: /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp

Comment: Could you provide a URL for a downloadable copy of `xah-find.el` ?