# What is the point of the Ctrl-M binding? Can I overwrite it if I use the Return key?

Tags: key-bindings

Looking for a new convenient keybinding for a frequently used command I stumbled upon Ctrl-M which is the same as Return/Enter.

What is the point of this binding? Can it cause some problem if I overwrite it?

Comment: This recent related Q&A might also be helpful: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/52328/454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII control character `Control M` is a carriage-return character. It *is* return, and its ASCII name is `RET`. That's the reason why `C-m` in Emacs is `RET`.

In terminal mode (no graphic display) Emacs does not have a `<return>` (pseudo-)function key. There is *only* the `RET` key, also known as `C-m`.

In a graphic-display Emacs has both a `<return>` key and a `RET` (`C-m`) key. **You can bind** either of them to **whatever command you like**.

If `<return>` is *not* explicitly bound then when you use `<return>` the binding of `RET` takes effect.

This is for *convenience* - it's the same principle that lets key `M` act as key `m` if `m` is bound to a command and `M` is not explicitly bound to a command.

---

As @phils mentioned in a comment here, see also [`C-h i g (elisp)Function Keys`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html).

Comment: So I if used Emacs in terminal (I don't) then I shouldn't rebind C-m, because then RET wouldn't work either?

Comment: If you rebind `C-m` then you've just rebound `RET`. They are the same thing. Whether rebinding it breaks something or not is another question. It likely won't "break" anything, but sometimes when you think `RET` (`C-m`) will do one thing it might do another instead. It depends on the keymap you rebind it in etc.

Comment: See also: `C-h i g (elisp)Function Keys`

Comment: @phils: Thx; I added that to the answer.