# A few org files are not displayed as org mode

Tags: org-mode

When I open file with C-x C-f `(counsel-find-file &optional INITIAL-INPUT)`

Most of the org files are opened as org-mode automatically, yet there are a few displayed as plain text as fundamental mode.

What's the problem it might be?

The example is the Chapter 5 of SICP

[image]

Issue M: and eval `(cl-rassoc 'org-mode auto-mode-alist)`, get output

```
("\\.org\\'" . org-mode)
```

[image]

```
Emacs 26.3 
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.11) of 2019-09-23, modified by Debian
```

the machine info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 
Host: MacBookPro11,1 1.0 
Kernel: 5.3.0-24-generic 
Uptime: 7 hours, 54 mins 
Packages: 2601 (dpkg), 2 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.3 
Resolution: 2560x1600 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin
```

Comment: What keyboard shortcut are you using to open the file, and what is the name of the function that is triggered?  `C-h k` and then type the keyboard shortcut to see which function is bound.  Also, do you have a minimal working example of a file that the behavior is exhibited?  If we have that information, then we can probably do away with our crystal ball when trying to answer this question. :)

Comment: Maybe have a look at section 23.3 "Choosing file modes" of the manual.

Comment: Please type `M-:` and thereafter in the minibuffer `(cl-rassoc 'org-mode auto-mode-alist)` followed by the RETURN key. Add the value that is output to the `*Messages*` buffer to your question.

Comment: ty, it print `org\\'" . org-mode)` . @Tobias

Comment: This looks wrong but I'm not sure whether it's a cut-and-paste error: is there no opening parenthesis and no opening double quote? In my case, I get `("\\.org$" . org-mode)` . Note that also the pattern is different in my case: you might want to check the setting of `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: @NickD `("\\.org\\'" . org-mode)` is also fine. Actually, it is closer to what is meant. The expression `$` at the end of the regexp is the match of the empty string at the end of line while `\\'` is the match of the empty string at the end of input, i.e., the string. A string may contain multiple lines. Then `$` and `\\'` can give different results.

Comment: I am so sorry it cut-and-paste error and it's in auto-mode-alist. I wonder if emacs has some mechanism which set fundamental mode automatically for so-long text? @NickD

Comment: What operating system and version of Emacs are you using (try `M-x emacs-version`)? Do the files with this problem have anything in common - same directory, similar name, any comments at the beginning or end of the files?

Comment: emacs 26.3 on ubuntu 19.10 @Tyler

Comment: Does the problem persist when you start emacs via `emacs -Q`?

Comment: N0, it works perfectly in a vanilla emacs @Tyler

Comment: ok. The problem is in your personal configuration then, and we'll have a hard time helping remotely. See here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems