# C-g doesn't work within Counsel's action menu (M-o)

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, ivy, counsel

Let's say I'm completing a file with `counsel-find-file`.  I then press `M-o` to show the menu with available actions.  If within that menu, I press `C-g`, I get the message "C-g is not bound".

The expected behavior would be for the menu to quit (and to go back to where I was completing the file name).

How can I set the behavior I want?  (I don't know what is the keymap used by Counsel's menu and also don't know how to quit the menu).

Comment: That's what it does for me (C-g quits the menu and returns me to the file selection interface)

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, likely there's something weird in your configuration that changed the default. The keymap is `ivy-minibuffer-map`, and it should include `(7 . minibuffer-keyboard-quit)` when you view it with `C-h v`.

Comment: Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems for tips about debugging your config, including how to load just one package, and no other customizations

Comment: Thanks you.  I created an init.el file that only loads Ivy and Counsel but still have the problem.  I'm using Emacs 26.3 on Linux.

Comment: that sounds like a bug. You might want to contact the package author - they'll want to know your Emacs version, and the version of counsel that you're using. That should be available from the package list.