# How to turn off R help document popup when using ESS?

Tags: company-mode, ess, company

When I input a function, the R help document pops up automatically. It's very annoying. How to turn it off? [image: screenshot]

Comment: it doesn't do this by default. There is probably something in your configuration causing this problem. You could start by bisecting it to narrow down the likely problem: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: I use doom-emacs. It might be not easy to do that. Is this functionality provided by ESS?

Comment: It's probably associated with ESS, but what you describe sounds very irritating - definitely not standard behaviour with ESS, which I also use extensively. I'm not familiar with Doom Emacs unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

This is an interaction of `company-mode` with ESS. You can fix this issue like this:

`(setq ess-use-company 'script-only)`

This disables use of `company-mode` in the R terminal, but makes it available in R scripts. To disable it entirely in ESS, just use

`(setq ess-use-company nil)`

More useful information about `company-mode` with ESS can be found here:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESS-company