# Emacs from an alias/function

Tags: start-up

```
uname -a Linux antixbox 4.9.235-antix.1-amd64-smp #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon
Sep 14 19:26:52 EEST 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 
emacs --version GNU Emacs 27.1

echo $SHELL /usr/bin/zsh
```

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
em() {   emacs $1 -geometry "56x23" }
```

I want to use it as follows e.g. with an existing file:

```
em testfile.txt
```

Emacs does launch, but no file buffer.

If I edit the function and replace `nano` for `emacs` (and get rid of the geometry stuff), the function works perfectly.

Comment: I have NO idea why the last sentences of my post are in bold!!

Comment: Does it work without a function? i.e., just typing `emacs filename -geometry "56x23"`?

Comment: @Tyler Nope! JUST discovered that! I can't finger it out. emacs does launch, but no file shows up.

Comment: Do you use the `dashboard` package? That causes this problem for me. Otherwise, you'll need to investigate your own configuration files to find the culprit.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for the `dashboard` headsup! I'll have to check in the antiX forum to see if it does get used. Thx for the URL!

Comment: Problem solved! Nuked emacs-27.1. Re-installed 26.1  All's well!  Thx

Comment: In any such function you would definitely want to replace `$1` with `"$@"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe run [Emacs as a server](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) and then edit files with *emacsclient*?

I have an alias

```
e='emacsclient -nw'
```

And is using it like

```
$ e foobar.txt
```

Comment: Also setting `EDITOR=emacsclient -nw` env var is handy

Comment: Благодарность!!  I'll give it a try to see if it solves my problem!

Comment: Did it help or you still need to run separate instance of *Emacs* every time?

Comment: It did! Thank you!