# Texinfo-mode invalid function

Tags: texinfo

On a fresh install of Emacs 27, I'm getting an `Invalid function: dbus-ignore-errors` error when trying to run `M-x texinfo-mode`.

I've tried using alternate extensions for the file (like ".texi" or ".texinfo") and function declaration at the top of file, but it seems to result in the same error.

This is the first time I've seen this error, so any troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Comment: First, rule out a problem in your config by running `emacs -Q` and seeing if the problem goes away https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: What @Tyler said. If you see the problem with `emacs -Q` then consider reporting it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If you don't see the problem then bisect your init file to find the culprit.