# C stackoverflow in my Prelude when edit .tex files

Tags: auctex

It occasionally happens to me that I get the notorious error message

```
Re-entering top level after C stack overflow
```

when I edit my `.tex` files.

I checked whether it occurs with `emacs -q` and it does not. It pops up only in my Prelude.

Now, my main problem is that I cannot debug it. This is what I've tried so far:

- Try to decrease `max-specpdl-size`,  `max-lisp-eval-depth`, and various undo limits as [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/1407), but it does not help.
- Tried to run `gdb emacs`. But the executable I have is not compiled with the debug symbols.

**How do I even detect where this error comes from?**

---

My workaround is that I open the file in `emacs -q` and paste the paragraph that caused my Prelude to crash. Then re-open the same file in Prelude and continue my work. This kinda suggests that the overflow happens in some checkers. To the best of my knowledge, the checkers run stuff as I type. It may be that some of them gets confused by some of my latex macros which eventually leads my whole Emacs to a stackoverflow.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Normally, we'd recommend bisecting your init file to find the source of your problem https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems . However, this is complicated with Prelude. You might have better luck using the support channels specific to that distribution: https://prelude.emacsredux.com/en/latest/support/

Comment: I see. However, the `emacs-prelude` tag here on SO is one of the suggested channels of communication for the Prelude distribution.