# List files opened by emacs

Tags: init-file

I am having trouble finding an init problem where `emacs -q` gets the error `Invalid face: highlight`, but `emacs -Q` does not.

I would like to list the files opened by emacs to track down this problem. Is there a command-line switch to have emacs print the names of the files as it is opening them?

I'm running emacs 27.2 on Ubuntu 21.04, x86_64. (Forced to use `vi` until the init problem is resolved!)

Comment: Probably you could have a look at the recentf-save-file (default "~.emacs.d/recentf").

Comment: Consider placing `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the outset of your `.emacs` / `init.el` file and restart ... perhaps there will be a more detailed backtrace of where the problem might be ...

Comment: When you say "files opened by Emacs" what do you mean? Do you mean the Lisp files it has loaded? The answer for that is `C-h v load-history` - it's a log of all libraries Emacs has loaded and what definitions it's gathered from each one.

Comment: The difficult thing is that emacs will not create a window when the Invalid face message is issued. Emacs is done when the message is issued to the console. I've renamed my ~/.emacs file and ~/.emacs.d directory so that they can't be accessed.

Comment: If the bug occurs with `emacs -q`, but not `emacs -Q`, the problem is most likely in your `site-start.el` file. See: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems