# org-mode input M with shift-m doesn't work

Tags: org-mode

When I try to input a capital M in org-mode with ubuntu, I always got a M- in minibuffer, so M letter can never being input to my document.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you say `C-h c S-m` in that org mode buffer, what do you get in the echo area? Does the problem occur if you start emacs with `emacs -q` (i.e. without your init file)?

Comment: it's weird, if with -q parameter, it works fine. so it's me add some bad config. but how to figure it out?

Comment: What does `C-h c S-m` say? If it is bound to function `foo`, then search in your init file for that name: chances are you'll find the culprit. A more systematic approach is to bisect your init file: see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: C-h c S-m will not work since Shift-M has been translated to M-, looks like I can not paste M into minibuffer either! Let me comment out it line by line to debug

Comment: Unless your init file is very short (less that a couple of dozen lines say), you are better off bisecting it.

Comment: @NickD I finally found the code. after comment out that line, it works fine now. but still not figure out why M-q map will impact on shift-m input.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @NickD's help.

Finally I found below line make the trouble:

```
(defun samplefunction()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-paragraph-function nil)
        (adaptive-fill-function nil))
    (fill-paragraph)))

(define-key org-mode-map "M-q" 'samplefunction)
```

This is define Meta-q, but not sure why it impackt on Shift-m.

Comment: Try `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-q") 'samplefunction)`   instead.

Comment: or change the line to `(define-key org-mode-map "\M-q" 'samplefunction)`  (see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html)