# `void-variable: Symbol’s value as variable is void: v` when deleting remote directory in dired

Tags: debugging, dired, tramp

This recently started happening. Whenever I try to recursively delete any remote directory from dired (i.e. `D` over the dired entry), I get this after Emacs asks me for confirmation:

```
void-variable: Symbol’s value as variable is void: v
```

I have no idea what's going on. The only change I remember making is updating Tramp from the built-in version (I'm running Emacs 27.1 on Debian) to the most recent ELPA version.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. And please present a recipe to repro the problem.

Comment: Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and do the command again: paste the resulting  backtrace into your question. Both @Drew's comment and this one describe standard debugging techniques for troubleshooting emacs problems. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems for these and other techniques.

Comment: Which Emacs / Tramp versions are you using? A recent Emacs from git master branch doesn't show this problem.