# ess-eval-line-visibly-and-step splits window and shows in both

Tags: ess

I've noticed that when I execute `ess-eval-line-visibly-and-step` inside an R-mode buffer and I don't already have an active R session, it will split the screen (good), however it will change both sides of the split into the R session (bad). I would expect it to split the screen and show the R session on one side (ideally the right) and leave the R-mode buffer on the other side (ideally the left).

The only bit of my init.el referencing ESS is

```
(use-package ess
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq ess-ask-for-ess-directory nil        ;; just run R wherever
                                             ;; the file lives
        ess-history-file nil                 ;; don't save history
        ess-eval-visibly-p nil               ;; when running R, don't
                                             ;; show code, just output
                                             ;; (greatly speeds
                                             ;; running)
        inferior-R-args
          "--no-restore --no-save --quiet"   ;; R startup conditions
        ess-style 'RStudio                   ;; better indenting
        comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-input   t ;; force ESS to scroll R
                                             ;; to the bottom after
                                             ;; running code
        comintq-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t
        comint-scroll-show-maximum-output  t
        comint-move-point-for-output       t))
```

I've commented out all the `setq` and it doesn't fix the issue.

What can I do to change the way this works? Is it a bug, a configuration issue, or some other problem?

I've run `emacs -Q`, then run:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-load-list
      '((ess t)))
(package-initialize)
```

And the issue still persists. Emacs 27.2 and ESS 20220225.1523.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to be saying only that you don't like some behavior you see. Maybe you want (elsewhere) to propose a bug fix or enhancement to the code of `ess-eval-line-visibly-and-step`?

Comment: The behavior I'm seeing appears incorrect. I'm trying to figure out if its a known issue that would require a fix, or if its something I'm not doing in my init.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. For me, it splits the screen into two windows, with my script in one and the R process in the other. Emacs 29.0.50, ESS 18.10.3, R 4.1.2

Comment: I've got ess-20220225.1523 installed in Emacs 27.2. I run emacs even without an init (emacs -q), run `package-initalize`, activate `r-mode`, then run `ess-eval-line-visibly-and-step` and I get the dual R windows as described above.

Comment: Running `package-initialize` like that will load *all* of your packages. So it's possible there's an interaction between ess and something else you've loaded. See **step 1b** here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: Please pose your question as a question - in the post itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions need to stand on their own. Thx.

Comment: I've edited to question to make it a question, as well as show that I loaded only ess per Tyler's question and the issue still persists.