# orgmode - expand babel results after execution

Tags: org-mode

I have installed latest orgmode (release_9.5.3-480-g0b07b3), after run C-c C-c to execute a babel code, the results block has been folded by default.
How can I config it to expand the results block by default after execution?

I use below drawer to show image since I want to show text output and image output at the same time.

```
#+begin_src python :results output drawer
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)

pngname = "./hello.png"
plt.savefig(pngname)
print("[[%s]]"%pngname)
#+end_src
```

This example works fine before, but latest org version will fold the results after execution! Looks like the drawer behavior changed.

Comment: Does it happen if you start emacs with `emacs -q`? If not, the problem is with your init file: [bisect it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems) to find out what causes it. If yes, does it happen with `emacs -Q`? If not, then the site initialization file is the problem: complain to your distro. One or the other of these should be the case, because by default, resutlts blocks are *not* folded.

Comment: @NickD Thanks, looks like the drawer behavior changed. I add a example in question and the output will be fold after execution.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that behavior. There has also been some discussion about it on the [mailing list](https://list.orgmode.org/9D0BF38C-01A1-4359-B529-7F6EAFC01D47@berkeley.edu/T/#m8930b5051fb5670b6a579076a8ade1eb1e10b382) although I'm not sure what the outcome is (if any): I haven't read it carefully enough.

Comment: @NickD Good findings, yes, I read it and one workaournd is add #+STARTUP: showeverything in org doc!

Comment: I thought they said that did not work - but as I said, I just skimmed.