# Stopping the message ‘[Saved text until: …]’

Tags: minibuffer, line-spacing

The problem I have is caused by `Emacs.lineSpacing: 1` in my X resources (thanks to NickD for help in pinpointing this), which equates to:

```el
(setq-default line-spacing 1)
```

With that in effect, I call `find-file` (`C-x C-f`) and my minibuffer says:

```
Find file: ~/.Xresources
```

There I select the file name and call `kill-ring-save` (`M-w`).  Now my minibuffer says:

```
Find file: ~/.Xresources [Saved text until: "~/.Xresources"]
```

How do I stop that appended message *and* retain a line spacing of 1?

Comment: What version of emacs are you running? I cannot reproduce it on emacs 29.0.50 from a couple of months ago.

Comment: @NickD 27.2, though I see now that 28.1 is out. Mind you, I suspect I did something in my init file that caused this, but I’ve no idea what. http://reluk.ca/.config/emacs/lisp/initialization.el

Comment: Can't reproduce it on 27.2 either. It's easy to check if your init file is behind this: start emacs with `emacs -Q` and try to reproduce. If you cannot, then your init file is the culprit: try [bisecting it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems).

Comment: @NickD Turns out I had to bisect `-Q`. The cause is `Emacs.lineSpacing: 1` in my [X resources](http://reluk.ca/.Xresources), which equates to `(setq-default line-spacing 1)`. But why that causes a recursive echo, I don’t know.

Comment: When you call `find-file` the input is read from the [Minibuffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer.html#Minibuffer), not the [Echo-Area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Echo-Area.html). `indicate-copied-region` emits a message that tells you the region you have copied. That is what you are seeing as text from the Echo Area in the brackets.

Comment: @Tobias, corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```el
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook (lambda () (setq line-spacing 0)))
```

It’s easier to figure when you know the cause.  Again, thanks to NickD for help with that.

Comment: After 24 hours you should be able to accept your own answer as solution. This marks the question as solved and it does no longer occur in the list of unanswered questions. To accept this answer, [click on the check mark below the arrow for down-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).