# org-babel python cause start emacs from a folder name contains .zip error

Tags: org-babel, directories

I have a folder contains .zip, say a.zip, and org-babel python enabled, then go to that folder and start emacs, I saw error message as below:

```
Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size



$ mkdir a.zip
$ cd a.zip
$ emacs
```

[image]

What's the reason emacs care about folder name? any way to prevent such error?

Comment: Does it happen when you start `emacs -Q`? If it does please add the emacs version and operating system, otherwise you can bisect your init file to find the cause.

Comment: What @matteol said.

Comment: @matteol, exactly a init.el issue, but how can I figure out what's the problem from init.el file?

Comment: See `Step 2` in the answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems) for some guidance on how to bisect your init file.

Comment: @NickD Great, it caused by org-babel python support, if remove  (python . t) from org-babel-load-languages, no such error anymore!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was due to user's init file.

Comment: I would like to say it's a issue of python org-babel.

Comment: The problem is that without additional investigation, you cannot really say that: e.g. I have python enabled in my Org babel configuration and I don't see a problem. So it's more complicated than you think and without (lots of) additional information, we really can't say what exactly is causing the problem.