# How to find out where the message comes from?

Tags: spacemacs, text-editing

I'm trying to use Espanso in Emacs GUI. But nothing expands and Emacs echoes the message: "Beginning of buffer". The same snippet works everywhere except Emacs. I want to know where the message comes from and why Espanso or any other text expanders does not work in Emacs. It does work with `emacs -q`. I'm using Emacs Mac port with spacemacs.

Comment: Since it works with `emacs -q`, the fault is with your init file. [Bisect it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems) to find out what the problem is.

Comment: @NickD The problem is that I use spacemacs, it has tons of settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `debug-on-message` to enter the debugger and show a traceback when a message is shown which matches the regex it is set to:

```lisp
(setq debug-on-message "Beginning of buffer")
```

To apply this to your `init.el` file, put the above in or close to its beginning (or if necessary in `early-init.el`) and restart Emacs. It might also work, but not necessarily so, by just running the code above and then evaluating the whole `init.el` file using `eval-buffer`.

Comment: That's really useful.  Thanks for sharing.