# Org-mode-map key doesnt change to nil

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

My go to method for changing a key in a major mode is to do this:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(progn
     (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-k") nil)))
```

But for `C-k` which is bound to `org-backward-heading-same-level` - this doesn't do anything.

When i check `C-h k` and press `C-k`, I get the following:

> C-k runs the command org-backward-heading-same-level (found in
> org-mode-map), which is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in
> ‘org.el’.

I also tried:

- with-eval-after-load, and
- define key with [remap ...]

They also didn't work.

My goal is to make `C-k` do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`C-k` is bound to `org-kill-line` by default (try with `emacs -Q`), *not* to `org-backward-heading-same-level` (which is bound to `C-c C-b` by default).

One possibility is that somewhere in your init file, you rebind `C-k` to `org-backward-heading-same-level` but that has nothing to do with loading `org`, so the `eval-after-load` may trigger early, but you rebind it afterwards. You should check your init file(s) for such a setting and just expunge it.

---

[Feel free to stop reading here and try to fix your problem. Afterwards and if you are curious, read the following, although I don't think it has anything to do with your immediate problem; but it may be useful in various obscure situations in the future.]

There is an additional wrinkle with `C-k` in particular however, that might be worth knowing (although it's firmly in the *advanced* category). `C-k` is normally bound to `kill-line` in most modes. Org mode redefines it but not by setting `C-k` in the keymap, but by [remapping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html) the `kill-line` command to `org-kill-line` - see [org-keys.el](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-keys.el#n536):

```el
(org-remap org-mode-map
       'self-insert-command    'org-self-insert-command
       'delete-char            'org-delete-char
       'delete-backward-char   'org-delete-backward-char
       'kill-line              'org-kill-line
       ...
```

You *can* undefine such remappings, but you have to use something like the following:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map [remap kill-line] nil)
```

although you should think through the implications.

And even after you do this, `C-k` is still bound in the global map to `kill-line`, so if you really want to make it do nothing, you will need to undefine it there as well. That is something I would *NOT* recommend however.

As I mentioned above, this is probably *NOT* the problem you are having; it is something to keep in the back of your mind for future reference. The moral of the story is that keymap handling can be a complicated subject in Emacs.

Comment: THank you for the detail here. I looked into it and when i run `emacs -Q`, you are correct the command is different. However, I have no place where i assign this function to a key. Looking deeper, `C-h k` says the following: `It is bound to C-c C-b, C-k, g k, <normal-state> C-k, <normal-state> g
k, <menu-bar> <org> <Navigate Headings> <Previous Same Level>.`

Comment: This function seems to have many keybinding that I did not set. But when I look at they `org-mode-map`, i can see its only assigned to one key.

Comment: If `emacs -Q` does not show the bindings, then your init file(s) (or maybe the init files that the distro adds - what exactly are you running both in terms of Emacs and in terms of an OS?) are the culprit: there is no other way for the keybindings to happen. So bisect it (them) to figure out what's doing this. See [How do I troubleshoot Emacs problems?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems) for some methods.

Comment: In my case (standard Emacs on Fedara 36), `C-h w org-backward-heading-same-level` gives me two bindings: `C-c C-b` and the menu binding `<menu-bar> <org> <Navigate Headings> <Previous Same Level>`. I found https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-04/msg00082.html where `gk` is an Evil keybinding that's added. No `C-k` though.