# Prevent temporary buffer from overwriting main buffer

Tags: org-mode, buffers, time-date

I am encountering a strange behavior where any temporary buffer overwrites the main buffer content.

Using `org time-stamp` for example; the expected behavior is:

1. Invoke org time-stamp from within an org document
2. Temporary buffer with dates is opened below the main buffer
3. Choose date / time
4. Date / time is inserted into the org file

Instead the time-stamp temporary buffer overwrites all the content of the main buffer and no date / time selection is possible.

This also occurs across functions that use a similar temporary buffer mechanism like org-capture. Any advice on how to fix this or what is causing this behavior?

```
system     Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Linux 5.19.0-50-generic x86_64 x
emacs      27.1 ~/.config/emacs/
doom       3.0.0-pre 
custom     ispell-dictionary warning-suppress-types package-selected-packages
           org-safe-remote-resources org-agenda-files custom-safe-themes
modules    :config use-package :completion company vertico :ui deft doom
           doom-dashboard doom-quit hl-todo modeline ophints (popup +defaults)
           treemacs vc-gutter vi-tilde-fringe workspaces :editor (evil +everywhere)
           file-templates fold snippets :emacs dired electric undo vc :checkers syntax
           (spell +flyspell) grammar :tools biblio (eval +overlay) lookup magit :lang
           emacs-lisp latex markdown (org + journal + pretty + roam2) python sh
           :config literate (default +bindings +smartparens)
packages   (evil-tutor) (org-bullets) (dashboard) (org-journal) (org-roam) (calfw)
           (beacon) (org-super-agenda) (org-modern) (ob-mermaid) (golden-ratio)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue starting from `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: No - starting from `emacs -Q` things appear to be functioning as expected. I'm assuming the fault is somewhere in my config, but I have no idea how to start backtracing / untangling it.

Comment: Recursive bisection is generally the best approach when you don't know where to start.  At each step eliminate ~half the remaining config and then re-test to find out whether the issue still exists.  The test result tells you which half the problem is in, so you then eliminate half of *that*, and so on.  It doesn't take very many iterations to narrow things down.

Comment: See [How to troubleshoot Emacs problems](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems).

Answer (score 1):

@phils approach mentioned above helped me solve it.

Culprit was `golden-ratio-mode` for future reference.

Comment: That seems like a bug in that library, then.  I suggest reporting it to the maintainer to see what they make of it.