# why does emacs open an empty buffer named "BLANK" on startup?

Tags: buffers, start-up

When I start emacs, it opens an empty buffer named `BLANK`. I have no idea where this comes from and would like to not have it there, since there's nothing in it and it clutters up the buffer list.

I do use desktop mode and lazy loading, but I don't see any references to something named `BLANK`.

How can I track down what this buffer is, how it gets opened, and how to get emacs to not open it?

Comment: Does it happen with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from [Hyperbole](https://www.gnu.org/software/hyperbole/man/hyperbole.html).

I still don't know why this was happening on startup, but the exact source of the empty buffer named `BLANK` is the `hycontrol--blank-buffer` variable in `hycontrol.el`, which is used by `hycontrol-window-display-buffer`.

The function is called when using `hycontrol-windows-grid` and your grid has more windows than buffers, and it fills in the remaining spaces with this fake, blank buffer.

Why was that always getting run when starting emacs? I have no idea.

But, just to make it more obvious what that buffer is (and that it can safely be ignored, killed, etc), I changed the definition from

```
(defvar hycontrol--blank-buffer (get-buffer-create "BLANK")
```

to

```
(defvar hycontrol--blank-buffer (get-buffer-create " *hycontrol--blank-buffer*")
```

Since byte-compiling that, the spurious blank buffer no longer appears
on startup, so perhaps there was some artifact about some update to
Hyperbole?

Comment: If it starts happening again, put `(debug-on-entry 'hycontrol-window-display-buffer)` early in your init (I'm assuming that's a function name).

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling trying to debug that -- I can use `C-u C-M-x` to instrument a function for `edebug` -- but that's useless when trying to debug during initialization. I knew there was this kind of thing I could put into the lisp source but couldn't remember it.