# List Adaptive Fill Keeps Growing for Lists in Olivetti Mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation, adaptive-fill-mode

I'm having trouble with my org lists. They seem to have an ever increasing amount of adaptive-fill as I nest them deeper and deeper.

A picture of the problem is below. These are all single lines in the source file, so this is something going on with org-indent I would think?

[image: A list who's adaptive fill continues to rise]

I'm glad to post whatever config seems relevant, though I've tweaked almost everything that seemed relevant to no use.

Any hunches as to what variables I could tweak (if any) to fix it?

All ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Does it happen with `emacs -q`? If not, then bisect your init file. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems