Emacs weird font since upgrade to Linux Mint 22
Emacs was working fine for me until I upgraded my OS from Linux Mint 21.3 to 22. I'm not sure what version of Emacs I was using, but now it's 29.3 Here is output from the inxi -b command:

(base) david@XPS:~$ inxi -b System:   Host: XPS Kernel:
6.8.0-39-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64   Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.7 Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma Machine:   Type: Desktop System: Dell
product: XPS 8910 v: 1.1.0
serial:    Mobo: Dell model: 0WPMFG v: A00 serial:  UEFI: Dell
v: 1.1.0 date: 02/10/2017 CPU:   Info: quad core Intel Core i7-6700 [MT MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 850
min/max: 800/4000 Graphics:   Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel   Device-2: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 730]
driver: nvidia v: 470.256.02   Device-3: Logitech C920 HD Pro Webcam
driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
type: USB   Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
loaded: modesetting,nouveau,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: N/A 3: 1680x1050~60Hz   API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: nvidia mesa v: 470.256.02
renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2 Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 3165 driver: iwlwifi   Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros
QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet driver: alx Drives:   Local Storage: total:
931.51 GiB used: 619.35 GiB (66.5%) Info:   Memory: total: 16 GiB available: 15.52 GiB used: 4.23 GiB (27.2%)   Processes: 345 Uptime:
3h 5m Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.34

Here is my .emacs file in my home directory, which specifies the inconsolata font, my preferred font.
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
'(ansi-color-faces-vector
  [default default default italic underline success warning error])
'(ansi-color-names-vector
  ["#242424" "#e5786d" "#95e454" "#cae682" "#8ac6f2" "#333366" "#ccaa8f" "#f6f3e8"])
'(custom-enabled-themes '(wheatgrass))
'(debug-on-error t)
'(save-place-mode t))
(custom-set-faces
;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
'(default ((t (:family "Inconsolata" :height 120 :width normal :foundry "PfEd" :slant normal :weight medium)))))


;;; This was installed by package-install.el.
;;; This provides support for the package system and
;;; interfacing with ELPA, the package archive.
;;; Move this code earlier if you want to reference
;;; packages in your .emacs.
;;;(when
;;;    (load
;;;     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/package.el"))
;;;  (package-initialize))

;;; Added for povray mode and centered cursor mode

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp")
(autoload 'pov-mode "pov-mode" "PoVray scene file mode" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pov\\'" . pov-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.inc\\'" . pov-mode))
(and
(require 'centered-cursor-mode)
(global-centered-cursor-mode +1))

But when I start emacs I see a strange font that isn't even monospace.

I can select my preferred font under options, and I save the setting but when I start Emacs again the same weird font appears.
I asked about this in a Linux Mint forum but no one responded.
I could try to provide further information if requested.

Please reformat the code in your question. Please bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you do that and you still have a question about the specific code in your init file that causes the problem, repost your narrower question. Thx.

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems/28430#28430 for hints on bisecting your init file.

If you place your cursor on one character using the "strange font" and say C-u C-x = what font does it report?

It may be that Inconsolata is no longer installed on your new version. Try installing it.

NM - I see you can select it from Options, so it must be installed...
