org-mode: finishing a heading and starting on some other text?
I've recently upgraded my Archlinux system, and emacs has picked up some curious tricks; or maybe something is wrong in my init file.  Anyway, I have an org file which consists mainly of descriptions of little technical tricks and descriptions of how to do things, in a three level hierarchy.  And it's my principal go-to if I can't remember how to do something.
Previously, if I wanted to add something new, I'd simply go to where I wanted in the file and type, say:
*** Monty Python Rat Tart

Just grab some rats, and bake them in a tart.

with the use of the Enter key for newlines.  But now this doesn't seem to work.  Newlines don't move me off the heading into plain text, but stay in heading mode, as though I was going to enter a multiline heading.  This means that I can't type the above, as I used to.
I don't know whether it's me being stupid (very often the case), or if I need to set a variable in my init file, but it's currently a bit annoying.

What does C-h k (describe-key) tell you about the binding of newline?

As a second step, do you have the same problem if you start with emacs -Q? If not, bisect your init file - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

If pressing Enter adds an unwanted indentation, you may check the variable org-adapt-indentation.

Thanks very much for all those suggestions; I'll check them out.  The last one, about org-adapt-indentation looks very promising.  And I'll try with emacs -Q as well.  Also checking the newline binding with C-h k.  Again, thank you!

I used the 'bug-hunter' package to find, and then remove, some files I'd set as require in my init file, which were causing difficulty.  As of now, with the file slightly cleaned up, I can use org-mode as before.  Again - thanks!
