Org doesn't resolve [[id:UUID::*subtree name][link name]] hyperlinks
I'm trying to make org links leveraging the org-id-link-to-org-use-id and org-id-link-consider-parent-id variables, as described in section 4.5 of the org manual (Org mode buffers paragraph's example). But org doesn't resolve these links.
I get these error:

org-roam-id-open: Cannot find entry with ID "3b654d4d-b4a9-4cf5-a5bf-d55335f3853e::*subtree name" with org-roam activated
org-id-open: Cannot find entry with ID "3b654d4d-b4a9-4cf5-a5bf-d55335f3853e::*subtree nwme" using a plain emacs -Q instance.

Whether the ID property is attached to a headline that is inside the same org file, or to another file's buffer properties leads to the same result.
EDIT: added the following example
Here is how I would do a minimal example:

create and save sractch.org
create an * example heading
add an ID property to that heading using org-id-get-create
create a ** first subtree heading under * example
create a ** second subtree heading following the first one
call org-store-link while point is under ** first subtree heading
call org-insert-link while point is under ** second subtree heading, enter the description test link.

Here is what I get (as raw text):
* example heading
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       f3805217-ff72-4dbe-b8aa-72a266eb5498
:END:
** first subtree heading

** second subtree heading

[[id:f3805217-ff72-4dbe-b8aa-72a266eb5498::*first subtree heading][test link]]

EDIT 2: This used to work as I updated to org 9.7.14 but now stopped working again!
EDIT 3: Trying to troubleshoot again. I've updated org to 9.7.15.
When I start emacs normally, i.e. using the systemd daemon + an emacsclient, org-version returns 9.7.15, and the minimal example fails with the org-roam-id-open message.
When I start a quick emacs -Q, two things happen:

Inside my Packages buffer, I see org 9.6.15 as built-in and org 9.7.15 as "dependency", while the latter is set as (manually) "installed" when I start emacs normally.
When I open an org file, org-version returns 9.6.15, so I'm unable to confirm that org 9.7 works as it should and that org-roam is the culprit.

Thanks for your help!

You need to show us details: what the values of the variables are, the referent in the file, how you store a link to it (with org-store-link?), how you insert the link in the file (with org-insert-link?), what the link looks like in the file. FWIW,  I cannot reproduce the problem with a simple Org file.

Thanks, I've updated the description

I copy and paste the above, do M-x org-id-update-id-locations to update my id file with the new id, and the link works fine. Try starting with emacs -Q: if it works there, then bisect your init file to find out what broke things - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems/28430#28430 That's essentially what I tried before (minus the org-id-update-id-locations since org-id-get-create did that for me) when I reported I could not reproduce it: and I still cannot reproduce it.

Also please report the version of Org mode you are using (M-x org-version will tell you).

Doesn't work with emacs -Q as stated above, the only difference is that org-roam-id-open is used in place of org-id-open if I use my personal config.
Here is the output of M-x org-version
Org mode version 9.6.15 (release_9.6.15 @ /usr/share/emacs/29.4/lisp/org/)

OK now I don't get it ?!
Following my answer below, everything worked fine, but now it stopped working again, while I'm now opening my files with org 9.7.14

What does not work? org-id-open or org-roam-id-open? If the former works, then everything is OK from the Org mode point of view: it's probably org-roam that might need updating (and it might need extra changes to make it compatible with Org mode 9.7).

Just edited the question. Is there a way I can force my emacs -Q to use org 9.7 ?
Thanks again for your help

Use a minimal init file: emacs -Q --load foo.el with foo.el containing something like this: (add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/org-9.7/install/dir") (require 'org).

Thanks, I can confirm there is indeed no problem with this setup (-Q + minimal file loading org-9.7). Your initial guess about org-roam being incompatible with org-id updates is very likely to be right. I'll try to identify the buggy functions.

Well, thanks for asking for a version check, this feature appeared in 9.7 as stated in the changelog
I'm not sure why, but my info pages were more up to date than my built-in org package…
