Problem capturing a new entry to another header in the current buffer
I am a Doom Emacs user if it is relevant to that issue.
I was initially trying to build templates with location finding functions when I found this bug (which I believe is a bug in my config, not org-capture to be clear), and I simplified my tests until I could make sure what the problem was.
The issue is that my cursor is moved to the capture target location after hitting C-c C-c in the capture buffer, regardless of the jump-to-captured option. I have no idea how to debug the issue further.
The templates below both move my cursor to the capture target location, and for all templates and functions I tested so far, changing the target to any file but current-buffer works as expected. Note that the "Backlog" header is present when I am testing.
("y" "Buffer Backlog" entry
      (file+olp buffer-name "Backlog")
      "** TODO %?"
      :jump-to-captured nil
      )

("z" "Buffer Backlog 2" entry
      (file+olp buffer-name "Backlog")
      "** TODO %?"
      )

Any idea on how to debug this issue would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Can you reproduce the problem with emacs -Q --load init.el with a minimal init file (or whatever the Doom equivalent of this command happens to be)?

I don't really understand the title of your question: are you initiating the capture from the buffer where you expect the capture will eventually be stored? If so, C-c C-c should leave you in that buffer.  Are you saying that you are in that buffer, but point has moved to the place where the capture ended up?

Yes I think you got it right. I want to capture new tasks under the "Backlog" level 1 header located in the very buffer I am initiating the capture from. I tried to make the title clearer, but was not very inspired, sorry. I do not know the equivalent to load Doom Emacs with a minimal config, I tried emacs --no-site-file --load ~/.doom.d/init.el, and I have the same behavior. My cursor is moved to the newly captured entry after hitting C-c C-c.

How do you define buffer-name?

I used (file+olp (lambda () (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))) "Backlog") in the capture template and, starting with emacs -Q, I cannot reproduce it: point is restored properly (with either template). It has to be a Doom "feature".

Thanks for trying out. I am convinced it is coming from me. I am just looking for a way to fix it. I have not found yet how to test with a default Doom Emacs to find out if it is coming from it or me, that is of course the first step. My instinct tells me it is coming from my config, and I am looking for a way to investigate further.

Bisecting your init file is probably the way to go, but I don't know anything about Doom, so YMMV. But see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems/28430#28430 for possible inspiration (although it deals with standard Emacs).

A custom function of mine was responsible. I should have found a way to debug my config before posting. Thanks for your help, and sorry if I wasted your time. Cheers.

NP - glad you found it. If you have Doom-specific debugging tips or tricks that helped you find it, you might want to post an answer to your question describing them. Other Doom users might find them useful.

As expected, the problem was coming from my config. More precisely a custom function triggered by a hook. This is not the first time a hook of mine messes with the org-capture process btw.
I do not know the canonical way to debug one's configuration file with Doom Emacs, but I use a "literate configuration" file which makes it easy to comment entire blocks at once. I found out recently that an org header could be commented (M-;), and when it is the case, the source blocks sitting below  a commented header are not tangled by org-babel.
This allowed me to narrow down the part of config responsible for that bug with relative ease. Hope that helps someone else.
