Folded headings have ellipses in square brackets
Using Doom Emacs.
Earlier, when I folded a heading, ellipses used to appear at the end.
After recent update to Emacs 29.1 Doom v 3.0.0-pre, the ellipses appear in square brackets. See below for an illustration:
* Folded Heading ... (Earlier behavior, desired)

* Folded Heading [...] (Current behavior, not desired)

I tried changing the theme, etc. but no use.
How do I get rid of those square brackets?

SInce it does not happen with standard Emacs, it has to be something that Doom is doing. Maybe you can do the equivalent of emacs -Q and if necessary, bisect your init file to figure out who the culprit is. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems/28430#28430 for some instruction (although it applies to standard Emacs, not to Doom).

You may've already tried, but I'm able to customize my ellipsis by storing a custom value as the org-ellipsis variable.
(setq org-ellipsis "…")
(note: I'm not on Doom)

That did it. Thanks a ton.
