org-babel-tangle sometimes garbles link comments
Context: I am relatively new to Emacs, and very new to org-mode. I have recently ported my init.el to a literate programming style using org-babel.
Problem: the output of M-x org-babel-tangle is inconsistent

sometimes, the tangled output is as I'd expect - under 4k lines of source code and comments.
sometimes, the tangled output will be approx 80k lines of mostly comments. All the source code is the same, but there are entire sections that have been embedded in the comment-links.

emacs -q is not exhibiting this issue, so I know it is in my own config. In my current config, tangle is only successful the first time I tangle the file in a given emacs session, and every subsequent tangle causes the garbled links.
To give an example of the output, if my (trimmed-down) org file looks like this:
tangle.org
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle yes :mkdirp yes :padline yes :comments both
* Setup Package Manager
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (defvar bootstrap-version)
  (let ((bootstrap-file
         (expand-file-name
          "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el"
          (or (bound-and-true-p straight-base-dir)
              user-emacs-directory)))
        (bootstrap-version 7))
    (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
      (with-current-buffer
          (url-retrieve-synchronously
           "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radian-software/straight.el/develop/install.el"
           'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (eval-print-last-sexp)))
    (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
#+END_SRC

Then I expect this output:
tangle.el
;; Setup Package Manager

;; [[file:tangle.org::*Setup Package Manager][Setup Package Manager:1]]
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name
        "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el"
        (or (bound-and-true-p straight-base-dir)
            user-emacs-directory)))
      (bootstrap-version 7))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radian-software/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
;; Setup Package Manager:1 ends here

But the garbled output might (it is inconsistent) look like this:
tangle.el
;; Setup Package Manager

;; [[file:tangle.org::+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
;;  (defvar bootstrap-version)
;;  (let ((bootstrap-file
;;  (expand-file-name
;;  "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el"
;;  (or (bound-and-true-p straight-base-dir)
;;  user-emacs-directory)))
;;  (bootstrap-version 7))
;;  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
;;  (with-current-buffer
;;  (url-retrieve-synchronously
;;  "https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/radian-software/straight.el/develop/install.el"
;;  'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
;;  (goto-char (point-max))
;;  (eval-print-last-sexp)))
;;  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
;; #+END_SRC][Setup Package Manager:1]]
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name
        "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el"
        (or (bound-and-true-p straight-base-dir)
            user-emacs-directory)))
      (bootstrap-version 7))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radian-software/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
;; Setup Package Manager:1 ends here


In the end I apparently fixed it without identifying what was causing the issue. I made some misc changes to my config to try to fix it (including removing a tangle-on-save hook), and then I stopped being able to reproduce it again even after undoing the apparent fix.
If not for the eventually-consistent "fails after the second try" behaviour, I'd put this down to a single accidentally corrupted instance of emacs, but I was able to repeatedly start emacs instances and reproduce the behaviour, so it must have stemmed from some version of my config, which I accidentally removed in the messy attempts to fix it. Next time I'll have to be more diligent about tagging a broken baseline commit so I can be sure about the fix.

You have to be systematic with these things. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems/28430#28430 for the beginnings of a method. And you have to avoid the temptation of "just change this one thing and then I'll change it back" - DAMHIKT.

I followed something close to that pretty well, I think my problem that I had no commit/snapshot of any code that consistently reproduced the problem, so when I fixed it and got to step 3, I had no way to produce a recipe. And it was not as simple as un-commenting things, because there were changes to make before "commenting it out" would work (due to peculiarities in my initial config that prevented manually tangling the org source file).
So I'd add a pair of steps. Before 1b: "snapshot before you make any changes" and during 2: "as soon as you can't repro, snapshot again".
